# Problem with manually installed files and libraries in /usr/local/

Tags: libraries, binary

I have trouble with a whole range of manually installed programs and libraries in `/usr/local/bin` and `/usr/local/lib`. This also extents to `/usr/local/share`.

One suggested solution is often to reinstall the files with `checkinstall` and then removing them. However, for many of the programs I don't have the sources any more or they fail to compile on my current setup.

Is it save to simply remove the conflicting files and libraries.

Alternatively, will the problem be resolved if I upgrade from trusty to xenial?

Comment: I have a range of scientific geoprocessing (Gdal, geos, etc..)  image processing (ITK, Opencv,...) libraries installed from source. Over the past two years this gre into a jungle and when ever I fix one problem, e.g. python bindings, I get a new problem, e.g. missing shared components.

Comment: Yes it is. So I was wondering if deleting files in usr/local/... combined with purging and reinstalling some packages would solve this problem, or if a dist-upgrade would possibly help or if I really have to go through a fresh install.